# How to make text take up the width of an image

Tags: css, sass

I have an h6 and some text beneath it. I have the height of the image to stay at 238px and the width to be auto so I can get the real ratio while keeping a height of 238px. Because I am dealing with images of different sizes and these will all be aligned.

Here is the catch, there is some text beneath that image and I want the text to be the same width as the image width. However, when there is an overflow the text keeps going past the image instead of going to a new line.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="photo URL here">
    <h6> Some random text that could be very long</h6>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.parent{
  display: inline-block;

  h6{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  img{
    height: 238px;
    width: auto;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

My question is how can I make the text beneath the image go to a newline once it reaches the end of the image.